# Passing a labels text from a ViewController to a MapViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I've got this app in which I need to pass an address displayed on a textLabel ( I am adding an invisible button over the textLabel.

So by tapping on the button, I pretend to pass the text from that View to another view which is a MapViewController to display that text and get directions using the Maps App from the iPhone.

I am trying to do this through performing a segue like this:

This inside my MainViewController :

```
@IBAction func goToMap(_ sender: Any? )  {

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.destination is MapViewController
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? MapViewController
        vc?.pinAddress = addressLabel.text!
    }
   }

}``



// pinAddress is declared inside the MapViewController and I need the text in the addressLabel that is actually in MainViewController.This is not working though...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `prepare(for segue` out of the `IBAaction`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {  
     let vc = segue.destination as! MapViewController
     vc.pinAddress = addressLabel.text!  
}  
@IBAction func goToMap(_ sender: Any? )  {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"segue",sender:nil)
}
```